# SalesForce DocuSign REST API createAndSendenvelope

Tags: docusignapi, apex, docusignapextoolkit

Can anyone give a sample apex code REST API example for createAndSendenvelope. I am using demo DocuSign sandbox and I get INCOMPLETE ENVELOPE error. I do have all the required elements in my envelope, so looking to see what I am missing or if I am not creating it in a correct manner. Below is the json that I pass as request and  I get response: "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. Content-Type does not contain boundary parameter."

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "status": "created",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "tabs": {
                "signHeretabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "15",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentid": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Sign Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "initialsTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "45",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "receipientId": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": null,
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Initials Here",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }],
                "dateSignedTabs": [{
                    "yPosition": "65",
                    "xPosition": "249",
                    "width": "100",
                    "tablabel": null,
                    "required": "TRUE",
                    "receipientid": "1",
                    "pagenumber": "1",
                    "fontSize": "Size12",
                    "font": "Calibri",
                    "documentid": "1",
                    "anchorYoffset": "-5",
                    "anchorXOffset": null,
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorString": "Date Signed",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                }]
            },
            "routingorder": "1",
            "rolename": "First Signer",
            "recipientid": "1",
            "name": "Marisol L Testcase",
            "email": "testfd1@gcpa.com"
        }]
    },
    "emailsubject": "TestDocuSign Call",
    "emailBlurb": "Test Email Blurb",
    "documents": [{
        "name": "Name1",
        "fileExtension": ".txt",
        "documentId": "1",
        "documentBase64": null
    }]
}

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Name1"; documentid=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNhbXBsZSBmaWxlIHVwbG9hZCBmb3IgdGVzdGluZy4=
--BOUNDARY--
```

Update: I could get rid of the boundary parameter error and now get "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line. **Envelope definition missing.**"

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: For some reason when I try to add my json string to the post it looks completely weird. I am newbie to StacOverFlow can you please suggest any other way?

Comment: I believe to format it you select your code and press Ctrl + K

Comment: documentBase64 isn't needed if you're going to do a multipart document, and emailSubject has a uppercase S. Actually most of your REST call has improper casing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put `"documentBase64": null` in the "documents" node as you are already passing document as multipart request and `"fileExtension"` should be `"txt" not ".txt"`. Now coming to the tabs assignment, you are mixing two strategies, one is X/Y position and another is Anchor String. You should use one of them, X/Y position will put a DocuSign tab at specified `X/Y position`, whereas `AnchorString` will try to find the that string in the document and if it finds then attaches the DocuSign tab on it. And there is no fall back strategy, means if anchor string is not available then put X/Y position, this is not possible. So either your document should have anchor string then use Anchor String strategy else, remove Anchor string related property from JSON and place tags as per X/Y position.